# How to split and return lines a line by a line on the page

Tags: jquery, html

```
var split = $('.split-location').val().split('\n');
var lines = [];
for(var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
  if(split[i]){
    lines.push($.trim(split[i]));
  }
  return lines;
}

<div class="split-location">
Singapore
USA
Aussie
</div>
```

On profile, the user type with enter for each address, but the problem is when it is saved, the addresses would be displayed on the webpage as:

```
Singapore USA Aussie
```

How to make lines break in new lines on webpage? Or add `<br>`?

Also need to add accordion as it is too text-lengthy if add more than 5 locations. If array[0] (first location) appear as it is, then after first location, the rest of the locations would go into accordion section panel in same line break.

Is there a such way to do that?

Thanks

**Update**

```
   var split = $('.split-locations').html().split('\n');
    var lines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i]) {
            lines.push($.trim(split[i]));
        }
        $('.split-locations').html("<pre>"+lines+"</pre>");
    }
```

Wanted to print each line a line by a line with `<pre>` tag

Also how to figure for the rest of the location after print first one so that they can go in accordion?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a `div` element doesnt have `val()`. You should use `html()` or `text()` for getting the inner content for that

```
var split = $('.split-location').html().split('\n');

var lines = [];
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i]) {
        lines.push($.trim(split[i]));
        alert(split[i]);
    }

}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNBRU/9/)

**Edit**

If you want to show them as separate lines in div, use like this

```
var split = $('.split-location').html().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
$('.split-location').html(split);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNBRU/15/)

Comment: thanks i know already change to html() but it doesn't show each of the new lines in html page.

Comment: also console keeps saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Comment: did you check the fiddle?

Comment: Yes i did but it doesnt work on my local because everything is dynamic. in your case, it doesn't print a line by a line on web page right? Because I tested and found on inspect that <br> is applied and it still doesn't show as <br> in html. Also do you know how to take first array out so to put rest of the arrays in the accordion?

Comment: the problem is now how to print lines 1 by 1. I tried to add <pre> but not behaving as I expected.